# What is the difference between POST.get("..") and POST[".."] in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, backend

I am beginner to django and i would like to know the difference between POST.get("..") and POST[".."].

```
def home(request):
   username=request.POST.get("username")
return render(request,{"username":username})
```

############

```
def home(request):
       username=request.POST["username"]
    return render(request,{"username":username})
```

Answer (score 3):

> `request.POST["username"]`

This will throw an **error(KeyError)** if the key is not found.

> `request.POST.get("username")`

This will return **None** if the key is not found.

And also, you can add a **default value** if the key is not found.

`request.POST.get("username", "your_desired_value")`

Comment: so can we use ` request.POST["username"]` in a try block if we want?

Comment: Yes, and you can handle the exception as you want.